# Can this JS forEach function made simpler or more elegant?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to search for key:value pairs in a JS multidimensional array. The code I wrote seems to work fine, but I want to know if there is a more elegant way of writing it with any of the ES6 techniques.
The array is basically an array of files which I am trying to loop through to find a certain key:value pair.

So the multidimensional array is like this:

Here is a screenshot of the json array
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbvxW.jpg

And this is the code:

```
const search = (key, val, arr, result) => {
  arr.forEach(folderItem => {
    if(folderItem[key] === val) {
      result.push(folderItem);
    } 
    if(folderItem.files && folderItem.files.length) search(key, val, folderItem.files, result);
  });
  return result;
}
let result = search('name', 'Folder2', [files], []);
```

Here is also an example pen
https://codepen.io/muhammadkazimsadiq/pen/YzXJEgO

Comment: Why is the example only on an external platform and not in the question itself (preferable as snippet)?

Comment: Why do you modify `result` directly but then also return it?

Comment: @Andreas can you guide me pls? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: What objective criteria will you be using to determine answers' "elegance"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and add the nested found items as well, without using another parameter for `result`.

```js
const
    files = { name: "files", is_dir: 1, url: "test", files: [{ name: "folder1", is_dir: 1, url: "test\\/folder1", files: [{ name: "folder1_1", is_dir: 1, url: "test\\/folder1\\/folder1_1", files: [{ name: "index.txt", is_dir: 0, url: "test\\/folder1\\/folder1_1\\/index.txt" }] }, { name: "folder1_2", is_dir: 1, url: "test\\/folder1\\/folder1_2", files: [{ name: "index.txt", is_dir: 0, url: "test\\/folder1\\/folder1_2\\/index.txt" }] }, { name: "index.txt", is_dir: 0, url: "test\\/folder1\\/index.txt" }] }, { name: "folder2", is_dir: 1, url: "test\\/folder2", files: [{ name: "folder2_1", is_dir: 1, url: "test\\/folder2\\/folder2_1", files: [{ name: "index.txt", is_dir: 0, url: "test\\/folder2\\/folder2_1\\/index.txt" }] }, { name: "folder2_2", is_dir: 1, url: "test\\/folder2\\/folder2_2", files: [{ name: "index.txt", is_dir: 0, url: "test\\/folder2\\/folder2_2\\/index.txt" }] }] }, { name: "folder3", is_dir: 1, url: "test\\/folder3", files: [] }, { name: "index.txt", is_dir: 0, url: "test\\/index.txt" }] },
    search = (key, val, arr) => arr.flatMap(folderItem => [
        ...(folderItem[key] === val ? [folderItem] : []), 
        ...search(key, val, folderItem.files || [])
    ]),
    result = search('name', 'folder2', [files]);

console.log(result);
```